# Keytool plugin eclipse not working

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, keytool

I have to connect a java program to a LDAP server over SSL.
I've installed Keytool plugin for Eclipse correctly.
Created the keystore, imported the .cer into the keystore and all these informations appear alongside the console tab, so in the Keytool tab.
I wonder myself why my program still got error over SSL, but works fine without it.
I also tried the console version of keytool and all is correct, all appears in the tab correctly but the program is not working.
So, what can be the problem? Configuration or anything else?
In conclusion, is there a test/code I can do to verify if the problem is connected also with my program, or is a general problem?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**
add to C:\Program Files....jre7\lib\security\cacerts **YOUR** .cer.
This, after creating a fake and useless keystore just to allow Eclipse to add the keytool tab, nearby console tab.